# Unable to send text message through AWS SNS from AWS CLI / Console / SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I get the folowwing error when using the SNS service.

```
 {
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "hash",
        "timestamp": "2019-02-15 17:23:08.352"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "destination": "+1xxxxxxxxxx",
        "smsType": "Promotional",
        "providerResponse": "Internal error",
        "dwellTimeMs": 137
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

I tried changing the region and phone number and type to Transactional.

[image: AWS IAM settings]

Comment: Do share the command you used on the CLI so it is easier to troubleshoot

Comment: Was it working at some point then stopped or it never worked ?

Comment: No, I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this on AWS CLI and it worked for me.

```
 aws sns publish --phone-number +5556223456 --message 'Success!'
```

Note that this needs you to have configured your AWS CLI with your AWS Secret Key and password before using.

Update:

Another possible reason would be that IAM policies does not have adequate permission. You will need the sns:publish permission as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I am using the same command and configured CLI (that's when I can see the above log). I just get the message ID displayed and the above error in logs.

Comment: Which country are you trying to send sms in? Have you checked if SNS SMS messaging is available in your country?

Comment: I'm using the service in US tried with us-east-1 and us-west-2

Comment: Oh SMS should be working in the US. Have you tried sending to a different network? Which version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version. I cannot send it through console as well. I added an image to question. Are the above settings correct?

Comment: Check if you have the sns:publish permission as shown in the screenshot I added with the update to my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188492/discussion-between-sashi-and-a-dev).